# What does "User was removed" mean?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, profile-page

In the reputation tab on [my profile](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/10863/luc?tab=reputation), it shows -10 for "User was removed". Obviously my account was not removed, so I don't understand what this means. Perhaps it's a bug and a post of mine was removed? If so, which?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The account of a user who had voted on your question has been deleted. Sometimes users do this themselves, rarely we have to do it for them.

When they delete their account, everything they touched goes away with them. See also [What does "user was removed" mean and why did my reputation change because of it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126470)

Comment: Are they always removed when a user leaves, or only when the option is ticked? Because if he wasn't spamming votes everywhere, it seems more logical to me to keep the votes. Not only does it affect other's reputation, it also shifts content on the site. Less votes means a higher chance on "tied" answers, which might make them be displayed in the wrong order (if the answer that was upvoted by the deleted user really was better, and I guess odds are it was because why else did the removed user upvote it?). Hmm or should I ask this elsewhere?

Comment: @Luc I think this particular user deleted their own account. It happens regardless of how a user's account was removed. This is definitely an MSO topic. You can see brought up, "[Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740)".

Comment: I had the same thing happen yesterday. Probably the same user.